# I found I can use decorator inner with classmethod like this. But it seems wrong?

Tags: python, decorator

```
class A:

    def start(self):
        pass
    def end(self):
        pass

    def a(fun):
        def _(self):
            print("start")
            self.start()
            fun(self)
            self.end()
            print("end")

        return _

    @a
    def b(self):
        print("b")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    A().b()
```

Here is the code.
Normally, I do not use decorator like this, defined a function outside of class is a good way.But if I need do something with self, I must declare decorator inside. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand your question... In your code you could move `def a` etc outside class `A` (before it) and nothing would change (well, `a` would not be a method of the class after that but it is broken anyway)

Comment: "But if I need do something with self, I must declare decorator inside." — This is not correct. You could have declared `a` as a standalone function and used it just the same as you have here.

Comment: @khelwood Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your query correctly, you want an outside defined decorator to use the variables limited to an instance of the class.

There's a way to do that.

#### Code

```py
def a(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(args, kwargs)
        print(dir(args[0]))
        print(args[0].name)
    return wrapper

class X:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Sid'
    @a
    def p(self):
        print self.name

x = X()
x.p()
```

#### Output

```sh
((<__main__.X instance at 0x7fcc440a38c0>,), {})
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'name', 'p']
Sid
```

Here, we've a decorator named `a`. It accepts `args` and `kwargs`. 
If you're decorating the class' method with this outside declared decorator, the class' instance is sent in the `args`.
You can use the `args` to get the variables under that instance.

Comment: Yes, I want to add a decorator, but define it inside of class, outside seems weird(I don't know why I think so). So I wanna try to write it inside. The code that I write is work, but pycharm always hint error. Anyway I give it up, just write outside.